# Signing parts of a URL with a RSAKey using Python instead of C#

Tags: python, rsa, sha1, signing

I do have a private RSAKey (in XML format) that was generated by a .NET class. Those keys, are regularly used to sign parts of a URL. I am trying to sign these URLs with the existing keys via Python, because I am working now in a Linux based environment. The structure of the RSAKey looks like so:

```
RSAKeyValue,Modulus,Exponent,P,Q,DP,InverseQ,D represented in XML format.
```

Using C#, I simply instantiate a RSACryptoServiceProvider object and call SignData(bytes, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()), and I am done. 
I have tried for several days now to replicate this process using Python in a Linux environment without any luck. I extracted modulus, and exponent, base64 decoded, and created byte arrays from them. I also changed the byte order. I was under the assumption that I could use M2Crypto and call RSA.new_pub_key((e,n)) and use that key to sign but no matter what I do I either can't create a proper key, or the signing process doesn't work.

My questions are:

-Is it possible to use an RSAKey in XML format that was generated via .NET, and sign data via Python (M2Crypto or any other lib will do) with the exact same result as in .NET ? 
If so, what are the exact steps to do so?

My apologies for the long question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure about the details of this, but you should be able to export a X.509 PKCS#12 certificate on .NET with the private/public key pair to a file and that should be usable by OpenSSL (M2Crypto or other Python OpenSSL wrapper).